# AWS Cloudfront remove particular cookie before sending to origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I want to remove particular cookie in aws cloudfront before sending to the origin server.
I have to send all cookies to origin except cookie named `"_x_ad_zone"`.

I could not find any option to remove particular cookie in cloud front configuration. I believe that we have to achieve with lambda, but I have no clue how to do it.

Please let me know how can I achieve the same.

[EDIT]
Based on the answer, I wrote the following lambda@edge to solve my issue.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    const cookieName = '__a_x_id';

    /*
     * Lambda at the Edge headers are array objects.
     *
     * Client may send multiple Cookie headers, i.e.:
     * > GET /viewerRes/test HTTP/1.1
     * > User-Agent: curl/7.18.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1u zlib/1.2.3
     * > Cookie: First=1; Second=2
     * > Cookie: ClientCode=abc
     * > Host: example.com
     *
     * You can access the first Cookie header at headers["cookie"][0].value
     * and the second at headers["cookie"][1].value.
     *
     * Header values are not parsed. In the example above,
     * headers["cookie"][0].value is equal to "First=1; Second=2"
     */
    console.log(headers.cookie);
    // Delete the cookie if found
    if (headers.cookie) {
        for (let i = 0; i < headers.cookie.length; i++) {
            console.log(headers.cookie[i].value);
            if (headers.cookie[i].value.indexOf(cookieName) >= 0) {
                console.log('Adblocker cookie found and delete: '+headers.cookie[i].value);
                headers.cookie[i].value = "0";
                break;
            }
        }
        request.headers = headers;
    }

    callback(null, request);
};
```

Comment: Do you really need to send **all** other cookies to the origin?  If this is true, you will be getting very few cache hits. It's better to send only specific cookies (or no cookies at all, where possible). If this is really what you need, please help us understand the reason this cookie needs to be removed so we can come up witn the most correct solution.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot We don't have to cache any thing at CloudFront, Our use case is to use CloudFront as a proxy gateway.

Comment: Kudos for jumping in an giving it a shot... but there are problems with your solution -- it might appear to work, but it's important to be pedantic when manipulating headers; what you have written has a hidden bug, because it can remove *other* cookies unexpectely, at random, and it is actually generating an invalid cookie header rather than cleanly removing the one you want to block.  I have developed a solution, which I will provide after I am able to thoroughly test it for expected and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quick disclaimer:  When cookies are forwarded to the origin server, CloudFront caches the response against not only the URI and the headers (and the query string, if configured to do so), but also against the unique combination of cookie values (or missing cookies) presented by the browser -- so a response can only be served from cache when they contain (or are missing) exactly the same combination of cookies and values.  This is not good for your cache hit rate, but of course, it also is completely correct design on the part of CloudFront -- if a different cookie is presented, CloudFront has no option but to assume that the cookie will potentially modify the response returned from the origin, so cookies must become components of the cache key.*

*It you must forward cookies, it's best to forward specific cookies.*

*However, CloudFront has a number of applications that are unrelated to caching, so there likely are valid use cases for a solution like this.*

---

Your solution will only pass simplistic and optimistic tests.  There are a number of edge cases it does not handle correctly.  The example script for cookie manipulation is only a simple illustration, and includes something of a disclaimer to that effect:

> ```
> * Header values are not parsed.
> ```

The first problem is that browsers are free to combine multiple cookies in a single `Cookie:` header, and your test of `headers.cookie[i].value.indexOf(cookieName)` will not only match a header with the cookie you want, it will match headers with that cookie *plus others*... and remove all the cookies in that particular header entry.

If used in a Viewer Request trigger, there's a significant risk of removing too many cookies with this solution.  In an Origin Request trigger, it's even higher, since the cookies have already been stripped and re-canonicalized by the cookie forwarding configuration of the matched Cache Behavior, and CloudFront *does* combine multiple cookies on a single header row, at least under some conditions.

The second problem is related to the first: the simple string matching of `indexOf()` will match cookie values, as well as cookie names, so it's possible to get a false match on a cookie *value* -- which you don't want to be examining.

The third problem is that you're not really generating a valid replacement value.  CloudFront seems to accept that, for now, but since it's technically invalid, there's a possibility that this could be "fixed" in the future.

I've written a Lambda@Edge script that I believe fully handles cookie semantics and will remove only and exactly the cookies you want to remove, and leave the data structures clean.  Because I find this to be an interesting use case, I wrote it so that it will match as many cookies as you like -- not just one cookie -- with an exact-string, case-sensitive match, on the cookie name only.

The cookies are configured in an array near the top.

In your case, with a cookie named `__a_x_id` would look like this:

```
const discard = [ '__a_x_id' ];
```

Adding multiple cookie names to the array will block all of them.

This uses Node.js 6.10 and works with either a Viewer Request trigger or an Origin Request trigger.  If you are doing any caching at all, you'll probably want to use it as an Origin Request trigger, since that means it fires less often.

I'm also pleased to report that in spite of looking a little complicated and doing a fair amount of string splitting and having multiple nested loops, this code has a Lambda execution time in a warm container of consistently less than 1 millisecond, whether or not any cookies are matched and removed.

```js
'use strict';

// source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45970883/1695906

// iterate through all Cookie: headers in a request trigger,
// removing any cookies on the "discard" list, while preserving
// the integrity of any other cookies, including those appearing on the same
// header line, and confirm the resulting "cookie" array to CloudFront 
// requirements by removing any now-empty elements, or the entire array
// if no cookies remain

// configure with one or more cookies to be removed from all requests;
// cookie names are case-sensitive

const discard = [ 'grover', 'big_bird' ]; // friends of cookie monster

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    // does the request have any cookies? skip to the end, if not
    if(headers.cookie)
    {
        const cookies = headers.cookie;

        // iterate each Cookie: header, from last to first;
        // last-to-first makes it simple to splice-out an array element
        // because we then need not keep track of the reduced array length

        for (var n = cookies.length; n--;)
        {
            // there may be multiple cookies per header line; examine them all

            const cval = cookies[n].value.split(/;\ /);
            const vlen = cval.length; // how many we started with

            // check individual cookies on this line, backwards
            for (var m = vlen; m--;)
            {
                // cookie name is to the left of "="
                const cookie_kv = cval[m].split('=')[0];
                // run though each member of "discard" array,
                // removing the cookie if it's a match, 
                // again last to first but for no particular reason, here
                for(var di = discard.length; di--;)
                {
                    if(cookie_kv == discard[di])
                    {
                        cval.splice(m,1); // cookie removed!
                        break; // no need to check any other matches, already gone
                    }
                }
            } // for m

            // if our array of cookies for this header line has now changed in size,
            // we must have deleted some or all of it, so we need to reassemble
            // what remains, or eliminate the entire line

            if(cval.length != vlen)
            {
                if(cval.length === 0) // did we remove everything?
                {
                    // yes? we can eliminate this entire line
                    cookies.splice(n,1); 
                }
                else
                {
                    // no? reassemble the remaining cookies
                    headers.cookie[n].value = cval.join('; '); 
                }
            }
        } // for n

        // if the only cookies present in the request were cookies we removed,
        // we now have a completely empty array in headers.cookie, which
        // CloudFront should consider invalid; clean it up
        if(cookies.length === 0) 
        {
            delete headers.cookie;
        }
    }

    // return control to CloudFront, possibly with our modified request
    return callback(null, request);

};
```

Comment: Amazing Solution ...Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to write an [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) function to conditionally filter the cookie in CloudFront.

Check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html) example to get an insight on required operations. Also note that you need to alter the request header in origin request event, using Lambda@Edge.