# Amazon Lambda@edge response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using AWS S3 and cloudfront to host a static site. I need to catch when the user agent is whatsapp or other...

So, I'm using `lambda@edge` function associated to a cloudfront with tiggers. Then, Tigger has 4 options (`viewer_request`, `origin_request`, `origin_response`, `viewer_response`). I'm develpoing a small script, tiggered on `viewer_request` that if the user agent is Whatsapp the response will be a pure html but if the user agent is any other the response should continue the natural flow and thus cloudfront should response a index.html configurated in the cloudfront properties. I can't do the flow continue to the index.html...

**My code:**

```
let content = ``;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   var response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

   const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
   const headers = JSON.stringify(request.headers);

   if(headers.toUpperCase().indexOf("WHATSAPP")>0) {
    console.log("is whatsapp");

    var html = `
    <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
        <head>
            <meta property="og:url" 
            content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-
            great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
            <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
            <meta property="og:title" content="When Great Minds Don’t Think 
            Alike" />
            <meta property="og:description" content="How much does culture 
            influence creative thinking?" />
            <meta property="og:image" 
    content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
        </head>
        <body>Whatsapp</body>
    </html>    
    `;

    response = {
        status: '200',
        statusDescription: 'OK',
        headers: {
            'cache-control': [{
                key: 'Cache-Control',
                value: 'max-age=100'
            }],
            'content-type': [{
                key: 'Content-Type',
                value: 'text/html'
            }],
            'content-encoding': [{
                key: 'Content-Encoding',
                value: 'UTF-8'
            }],
        },
        body: html,
    };
    context.succeed(response);    
   } else {  
    context.succeed(null);
   }
```

Comment: I think you still need to pass `context.succeed()` the unmodified response instead of just `null`.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work... I tried context.succeed(null,response);

Comment: Hey @criabdala were u able to solve it ? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and I fixed my problem by separating into 2 lambda functions, one handles `request`, the other handles `response`.

1. In CloudFront behavior settings, choose `viewer request` for the one processes `request`. And choose `origin response` for the one processes `response`.
2. For the `request` one, remember to `return callback(null, request)` as @michael-sqlbot mentioned.

**Note:**

- `viewer request` contains raw user agent from request headers, e.g. `"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`
- `origin request` contains CloudFront processed headers, e.g. `"Amazon CloudFront"`

Hope this helps and please correct me if anything wrong.

Reference:

- [Difference between event types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_LambdaFunctionAssociation.html)
- [Lambda at edge examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

To allow request processing by CloudFront to continue from a Viewer Request or Origin Request trigger:

```
return callback(null,request);
```

Comment: didn't work...  "The Lambda function returnedÂ invalid json: The json outputÂ mustÂ be an object type".

Comment: If this is a Viewer Request or Origin Request trigger, then this is the correct solution, assuming `request` is equivalent to `event.Records[0].cf.request`.  
[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45970883/1695906), [Example 2](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=812462&#812462), [Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html).

Comment: with apigateway we can change the response content-type and force to be a json... but in this case we are not passing througth api gateway...

Comment: This error is referring to the serialized JSON response from Lambda (which is *always* a JSON response, and this has nothing to do with your payload content).  It means you returned something that was not a JavaScript object.  If you insist on using the deprecated `context` methods, don't include the leading null.  `context.succeed(request)` is equivalent to `callback(null,request)`.