# Pass cookie to CloudFront origin but prevent from caching

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, foshttpcachebundle

I am using CloudFront as cache in front of my Symfony web application. To get a cache based on a user's role (admin, customer,...) I generate a user role based hash in a Lambda@Edge Viewer Request trigger. I pass that hash on as a request header to my origin as `X-User-Context-Hash`.

My problem is now that I need to pass the `PHPSESSID` cookie on to my origin to get the right response for caching, but I do not want to base the cache on the value of `PHPSESSID`. I do only need my cached response to be based on the value of `X-User-Context-Hash` but not on my session cookie.

The image below should explain my problem in detail

Is there any possibility to accomplish that?

Would appreciate any help.

[image]

Here's my Lambda@Edge Viewer Request trigger:

```
'use strict';

function parseCookies(headers) {
    const parsedCookie = {};
    if (headers.cookie) {

        console.log(`${headers.cookie[0].value}`);

        headers.cookie[0].value.split(';').forEach((cookie) => {
            if (cookie) {
                const parts = cookie.split('=');
                parsedCookie[parts[0].trim()] = parts[1].trim();
            }
        });
    }
    return parsedCookie;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    const https = require('https');

    // Read session cookie
    const parsedCookies = parseCookies(headers);
    let cookie = '';
    if (parsedCookies) {
        if(parsedCookies['PHPSESSID']) {
            cookie = `PHPSESSID=${parsedCookies['PHPSESSID']}`;
        }
    }

    console.log(`Cookie: ${cookie}`);

    // Send request to origin host at /_fos_user_context_hash
    // passing the original session cookie
    const options = {
        hostname: `${request.headers.host[0].value}`,
        port: 443,
        path: '/_fos_user_context_hash',
        method: 'HEAD',
        headers: {
            'Cookie': cookie, 
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.fos.user-context-hash',
            'Vary' : 'Cookie'
        }
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
      console.log('headers:', res.headers);

      // Read the X-User-Context-Hash from the hash endpoint
      const headerName = 'X-User-Context-Hash';
      let hash = 'anonymous';

      if (res.headers[headerName.toLowerCase()]) {
        hash = res.headers[headerName.toLowerCase()];
      }

      // Append X-User-Context-Hash before passing request on to CF
      request.headers[headerName.toLowerCase()] = [{ key: headerName, value: hash }];  

      callback(null, request);

    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
      // Forward request anyway
      callback(null, request);
    });

    req.end();
}


;
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I finally solved my problem:

### CloudFront behavior

I configured the behavior not to forward any cookies to the origin, but only cache based on the headers `Host` and `X-User-Context-Hash` (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot CloudFront behavior]

The following image explains my lambda@edge process:
[image: lambda@edge process]

1. In the "Viewer Request" trigger I read the user-based cookies named `PHPSESSID` and `REMEMBERME` and pass those values via the `X-Session-Cookies` header on.
2. If the there's a match for my request url and the given `Host` and `X-User-Context-Hash` headers, Cloud-Front returns the cached item and stops here.
3. If there's no match the "Origin Request" trigger is fired. When that event fires the custom header `X-Session-Cookies` is available. So I take the value from the `X-Session-Cookies` header and set the value of `request.headers.cookie` to that value. This step ensures that the `PHPSESSID` and `REMEMBERME` cookie are both passed to the origin before the page gets cached.

### My Lambda@Edge functions:

**The Viewer Request trigger:**

```
'use strict';

function parseCookies(headers) {
    const parsedCookie = {};
    if (headers.cookie) {

        console.log(`${headers.cookie[0].value}`);

        headers.cookie[0].value.split(';').forEach((cookie) => {
            if (cookie) {
                const parts = cookie.split('=');
                parsedCookie[parts[0].trim()] = parts[1].trim();
            }
        });
    }
    return parsedCookie;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    const https = require('https');

    let sessionId = '';

    // Read session cookie
    const parsedCookies = parseCookies(headers);
    let cookie = '';
    if (parsedCookies) {
        if(parsedCookies['PHPSESSID']) {
            cookie = `PHPSESSID=${parsedCookies['PHPSESSID']}`;
        }
        if(parsedCookies['REMEMBERME']) {
            if (cookie.length > 0) {
                cookie += ';';
            }
            cookie += `REMEMBERME=${parsedCookies['REMEMBERME']}`;
        }
    }

    console.log(`Cookie: ${cookie}`);

    // Send request to origin host at /_fos_user_context_hash
    // passing the original session cookie
    const options = {
        hostname: `${request.headers.host[0].value}`,
        port: 443,
        path: '/_fos_user_context_hash',
        method: 'HEAD',
        headers: {
            'Cookie': cookie, 
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.fos.user-context-hash',
            'Vary' : 'Cookie'
        }
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
      console.log('headers:', res.headers);

      // Read the X-User-Context-Hash from the hash endpoint
      const headerName = 'X-User-Context-Hash';
      let hash = 'anonymous';

      if (res.headers[headerName.toLowerCase()]) {
        hash = res.headers[headerName.toLowerCase()];
      }

      // Append X-User-Context-Hash before passing request on to CF
      request.headers[headerName.toLowerCase()] = [{ key: headerName, value: hash }];

      const sessionHeaderName = 'X-Session-Cookies';
      request.headers[sessionHeaderName.toLowerCase()] = [{ key: sessionHeaderName, value: cookie }];  

      callback(null, request);

    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
      // Forward request anyway
      callback(null, request);
    });

    req.end();
}


;
```

**The Origin Request trigger:**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    const sessionHeaderName = 'X-Session-Cookies';

    let cookie = '';
    if (request.headers[sessionHeaderName.toLowerCase()]) {
        console.log(request.headers[sessionHeaderName.toLowerCase()]);
        cookie = request.headers[sessionHeaderName.toLowerCase()][0].value;
    }

    request.headers.cookie = [{ key : 'Cookie', value : cookie }];

    callback(null, request);
};
```

Answer (score 8):

AWS recently [introduced](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-announces-cache-and-origin-request-policies/) cache and origin request policies, allowing more customization.

You can now set cache behavior based on "All-except" list of cookies/query string params by setting appropriate cache policy and set origin request policy to forward only necessary data:

[image]

Comment: This worked great for me and should the be accepted answer now that the functionality is available.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem:

> If you configure CloudFront to forward cookies to your origin, CloudFront caches based on cookie values.  This is true even if your origin ignores the cookie values in the request...
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Cookies.html

This is by design.  Cookies you forward are always part of the cache key.

There is no clean/simple/obvious workaround.

You could add the session cookie to the query string in the viewer request trigger, and configure that parameter to forward but not be used for caching, and then your origin would need to find it there and interpret it as a cookie.  Query string parameters, unlike cookies, can be configured for forwarding, but not caching.

You could potentially replace the cookie in the actual request with a dummy/placeholder value, one per user class, so that it would be forwarded to the origin and used for caching, and then use a viewer-response trigger to prevent any `Set-Cookie` response from the origin (or cache) from exposing that magic cookie to any viewers.

Really, though, it sounds as if you may be trying to solve a problem in one place that really needs to be solved in another.  Your application has a limitation in its design that is not cache friendly for certain resources.  Those resources need to be designed to interact in a cache-friendly way, which is of course a fundamentally tricky proposition when access to the resource requires authenticated identification of a user, role, group, permission, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, see my post below how I finally solved my problem. My problem was actually that the AWS documentation does not explain anywhere that headers from the Viewer Request trigger are not removed before the Origin Request trigger fires.

Comment: Most headers that are not configured for whitelisting are dropped from the request before the cache is checked, which occurs before the Origin Request trigger fires, so they wouldn't be visible there either, unless whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar I did to be able to forward cookies to an ALB configured for sticky sessions without cloudfront using the cookies to cache. The reason for this is because cloudfront will use the cookies and their values when matching requests and cached responses but because the ALB creates a new session cookie on each response, the request never matches the cache since the viewer always has a new cookie value set.

I too moved the cookie to a custom header in the viewer request and then pulled it out of the header and placed in back in the cookie in the origin request. I used the same lambda function for the viewer request and origin request and just checked the config property to determine which trigger it was. I prefer this pattern so that I can follow the logic from viewer request to origin request when reading/writing the code since the callback response from the viewer requests becomes the event request for the origin request and I could run my tests on a single function. The logic is based on three flows:

1. where there is no AWSALB cookie or customer header at all - in that case do nothing
2. where there is the AWSALB cookie but no other cookies in the request
3. where this is the AWSALB cookie along with other cookies

Using these three use cases the function was able to work properly.

Here's the function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
// TODO implement
const util = require('util');

const COOKIE_TO_FORWARD = 'AWSALB';

let hasTheHeader = (request, headerKey) => {
    if (request.headers[headerKey]) {
        return true;
    } 
    else return false;
}

//Returns the cookie key name from the value of the cookie header in the request
//let getCookieKey = cookieString => cookieString.slice(0,cookieString.indexOf("="));


const request = event.Records[0].cf.request
if(event.Records[0].cf.config.eventType == 'viewer-request') {
    console.log('Viewer Request');
    console.log(`viewer request – ${util.inspect(event, {showHidden: false, depth: null})}`);
    hasTheHeader(event.Records[0].cf.request, 'cookie') ? console.log(`This request has cookies`) : console.log(`This request does NOT have cookies`);

    // First check – If no cookies in Viewer Request, do nothing
    if (!hasTheHeader(request, 'cookie')) {
        console.log('viewer request first check evaluated - no cookies');

        //pass request onto cloudfront cacheing layer or origin request
        callback(null, request);

        return;
    }


   // else there is a cookie header so get the list of cookies and put them in an array
   let cookieList = request.headers.cookie[0].value.split('; ');
   console.log(cookieList);

    // Second check - If only the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD cookie exists and no other cookies, move it to a custom header and delete the cookie header

    if ( (cookieList.length == 1) && (cookieList[0].startsWith(COOKIE_TO_FORWARD)) ) {
        console.log('viewer request second check evaluated - only the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD cookie exists, no other cookies')

        //move awsalb to custom header - format is important
        request.headers.awsalbkey = [{'key': 'awsAlbKey', 'value': cookieList[0]}];

        //remove cookie header
        delete request.headers.cookie;

        console.log(util.inspect(request, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
        //pass request onto cloudfront cacheing layer or origin request
        callback(null, request);

        return;
    }

    // Third check - If there are multiple cookies including the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD cookie, move only the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD cookie to a custom header and delete the cookie COOKIE_TO_FORWARD cookie

    // get awsAlb cookie
    const indexOfAwsALbCookie = cookieList.findIndex(element => element.startsWith('AWSALB='));
    if ( (cookieList.length > 1) && (indexOfAwsALbCookie > -1) ) {
        console.log('viewer request third check evaluated - the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD cookie exists along with other cookies')


        //put awsAlb cookie value to custom header - format is important
        request.headers.awsalbkey = [{'key': 'awsAlbKey', 'value': cookieList[indexOfAwsALbCookie]}];

        //remove awsAlb cookie from list off cookies in request
        cookieList.splice(indexOfAwsALbCookie,1);
        let cookieListString = cookieList.join('; ');
        request.headers.cookie[0].value = cookieListString;

        console.log(util.inspect(request, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
        //pass request onto cloudfront cacheing layer or origin request
        callback(null, request);

        return;
    }


}
else if(event.Records[0].cf.config.eventType == 'origin-request') {
    console.log('Origin Request');
    console.log(`origin request – ${util.inspect(event, {showHidden: false, depth: null})}`);
    hasTheHeader(request, 'cookie') ? console.log(`This request has cookies`) : console.log(`This request does NOT have cookies`);

    // First check – If no cookies in Viewer Request AND no awsalbkey header, do nothing as this is the first request to the origin
    if (!hasTheHeader(request, 'cookie') && !hasTheHeader(request, 'awsalbkey')) {
        console.log('origin request first check evaluated - no cookies and no awsalbkey header');

        //send request to origin
        callback(null, request);

        return;
    }



    //Second check, if no cookie header AND COOKIE_TO_FORWARD customer header exists, then add the cookie header and cookie and remove the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD custom header
    if (!hasTheHeader(request, 'cookie') && hasTheHeader(request, 'awsalbkey')) {
        console.log('origin request second check evaluated - no cookies and has the awsalbkey header')

        //add the cookie header and the cookie obtained from the custom header
        request.headers.cookie = [];    
        var length = request.headers.cookie.push({'key': 'Cookie', 'value': request.headers.awsalbkey[0].value});

        //remove the custom header
        delete request.headers.awsalbkey;

        console.log(util.inspect(request, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
        //send request to origin
        callback(null, request);

        return;
    }

    //else cookie list exists
    let cookieListOrigin = request.headers.cookie[0].value.split('; ');
    console.log(cookieListOrigin);

    // Third check - If there are multiple cookies excluding the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD cookie and there's an COOKIE_TO_FORWARD custom header, move the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD custom header to the list of cookies and remove the COOKIE_TO_FORWARD custom header
    let originIndexAwsAlbCookie = cookieListOrigin.findIndex(element =>  element.startsWith(COOKIE_TO_FORWARD));

    if ( (originIndexAwsAlbCookie < 0) && (cookieListOrigin.length > 0) && (request.headers.awsalbkey) ) {
        console.log('origin request third check evaluated - cookies exist without the awsalb cookie and has the awsalbkey header')

        //add the awsalb customer header value to a new cookie in the cookie array

        var length = cookieListOrigin.push(request.headers.awsalbkey[0].value);
        let cookieListOriginString = cookieListOrigin.join('; ');
        request.headers.cookie[0].value = cookieListOriginString;

        //remove the custom header
        delete request.headers.awsalbkey;

        console.log(util.inspect(request, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
        //send request to origin
        callback(null, request);

        return;
    }


}

callback(null, request);
};
```